# Android: Output of thread on UI after it finishes its execution

Tags: android, multithreading

Basically I have 2 tabs.

In which ***first*** tab contains the data, and the ***second*** one contains some summary kind of data based on first tab's data.

In the first tab there is list of events. Whenever the there is an add/update/delete operation on events the summary needs to recalculated. The recalculated summary creates the list of rows in the database. And from those rows the summary tab is displayed.

So the problem is summary calculation takes long amount of time. So it is blocking the UI thread. So I moved the calculations in the thread for smooth UI operations.

Now as summary calculation is running in thread, I don't know when the calculation is complete and now I need to update the **summary** tab data and showing something while calculation is going on.

---

The current setup which I have is something like this:

My DatabaseHelper Class:

```
add() {
    ...
    // Do Add operation 
    ...

    reCalculateSummary();
}

remove() {
    ...
    // Do remove operation 
    ...

    reCalculateSummary();
}

reCalculateSummary() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...
            // calculate summary (may call another method)
            ...

            // Add calculated summary to DB
        }
    }).start();

}
```

While the `reCalculateSummary()` is running, the summary to tab should show loading message.

So How can I achieve this whole situation working?

How can I know if thread has completed its execution? So that I can update summary tab data by retrieving new db values of summary data.

So here is some confusing situation. Please feel free to ask if you have any doubts in understanding the situation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use an event bus, so you can update the UI, and avoid the limitation on AsyncTasks.

You can create the event "recalculateSummary", and just before job start (think of it as onPreExecute), update the UI with something that shows the user that the information on screen is not up-to-date, and update results when job is done.

Examples on event buses are [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), [AutoBus](http://opensource.bq.com/autobus/) ...

Comment: What is EventBus? Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Event buses are frameworks that enables your app to send/receive events from and to different parts of the app, related or not. You can send an event in a part of your code, and have "event listeners" that will do a task when its received. Think of it as internal messaging inside the app. This greatly improves your flexibility while executing asynchronous operations.

Comment: My answer has examples of it, please follow the links and read their documentation/web for more details. Probably they will explain what a event bus is better than me :)

Comment: Yup.. Thanks! I understood the concept :)

Comment: Glad to see I helped! :)

Comment: Can setting a variable in sharedpreferences while calculation running and setting onPreferenceChangeListener in summary tab activity work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98583/discussion-between-webo80-and-kirtan403).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **AsyncTask**.
Do the processing in the *doInBackground(..)* method, and update the UI inside *onPostExcecute(..)* method

Comment: Both the things are happening in different Activities. Like add() method is called by another activity and summary is contained in another activity.

Comment: You can pass the view which is to be updated, but keep a WeakReference, so as not to have any memory leaks in case the view is destoryed in the process. But in second thought, EventBus (as suggested in another answer) would be a better approach.

Comment: @kirtan403 - The solution would be to simply pass the data to the new Activity when you start it. And if the new data hasn't come in yet, there would be nothing to show anywhere because nothing has changed yet. The first tab would likely have a loading circle or something to show the user it is still working and so the summary isn't ready yet.

Comment: @NoChinDelux No, the data in the first tab is actually ready. But the data in the second tab is being calculated from the data present in the first tab.

Comment: @kirtan403 - OK even better! So you start the second Activity, show a loading circle while it processes the data, then update the UI when its ready. That's very simple to set up with `AsyncTask`

Comment: But the actions are in different activities. That is the issue.

Comment: Continue this in chat, stop spamming this answer.